# HDD format supported by 50 GB files in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ntfs

I just formatted my *HDD 2 TB Buffalo* to NTFS by Debian 8.1 but noticed that my Ubuntu does not like read it by giving an alert that the NTFS format is not readable by the system. 
I need to transfer files which size is 50 GB from my Ubuntu to the HDD. 
I will transfer the data through USB3.

Which format is suitable for big files in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you don't need to read it in windows, switch to another filesystem like xfs. the NTFS partition is not readable may be because you didn't unmount cleanly on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDD 2 TB recommended partition table is `GPT`.

GUID Partition Table is a partitioning scheme that is part of the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface specification; it uses a globally unique identifier for qualifying devices.

`Xfs` is a file system that was designed from day one for computer systems 
with large numbers of CPUs and large disk arrays.

It focuses on supporting large files and good streaming I/O performance. It also has some interesting administrative features not supported by other Linux file systems.

[Xfs file system](http://www.linux.org/threads/xfs-file-system.4364/)

[G.P.T.](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/730440-using-the-new-guid-partition-table-in-linux-good-bye-ancient-mbr-)

Comment: Probably supported by Debian and Red hat since it focuses on performance? Ok, not possible to format to it in Debian 8.1. I have just 3 years old Ubuntu at the moment. I am installing `xfsprogs`.

Comment: I did XFS on my disc but the Redhat variant Cern Linux 5 rejects this kind of discs. Any other possibility for big files in filesystems?

Comment: Maybe  btrfs, but I do not know.